# Remove a dimension from the output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have built this simple LSTM model, that provides output in 3 dimensions same as my input. But my target data is in 2 dimension. Is there any way to average out the output in a particular access.

```
batch_sizes = 1
epochs = 2
timesteps = 20

inputs_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (20,10),batch_size = batch_sizes)
lstm_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(inputs_1_mae) 
lstm_2_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(lstm_1_mae) 

output_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 10)(lstm_2_mae) 

regressor_mae = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inputs_1_mae ,outputs = output_1_mae) 
regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae") 
regressor_mae.summary() 

regressor_mae.fit(final_x_array, final_y_array, batch_size = batch_sizes, epochs=epochs)
```

Here is the summary of the model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_16 (InputLayer)       [(1, 20, 10)]             0         
                                                                 
 lstm_17 (LSTM)              (1, 20, 10)               840       
                                                                 
 lstm_18 (LSTM)              (1, 20, 10)               840       
                                                                 
 dense_16 (Dense)            (1, 20, 10)               110
```

I want the output to be in the shape (1,10). How do I eliminate that particular axis ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just **remove return_sequences = True of your last lstm layer** because you just need the last output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Lambda layer to accomplish that. The following may help:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_sizes = 1
epochs = 2
timesteps = 20

inputs_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (20,10),batch_size = batch_sizes)
lstm_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(inputs_1_mae) 
lstm_2_mae = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10, stateful = True, return_sequences = True)(lstm_1_mae) 

output_1_mae = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 10)(lstm_2_mae) 

output_1_mae_avg=tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda var_x: tf.keras.backend.mean(var_x, axis=1),)(output_1_mae)

regressor_mae = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inputs_1_mae ,outputs=output_1_mae_avg) 
regressor_mae.compile (optimizer = "adam", loss = "mae") 
regressor_mae.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(1, 20, 10)]             0         
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (1, 20, 10)               840       
                                                                 
 lstm_3 (LSTM)               (1, 20, 10)               840       
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (1, 20, 10)               110       
                                                                 
 lambda_1 (Lambda)           (1, 10)                   0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,790
Trainable params: 1,790
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```